# How to define multiple handler for a single event on serverless?

Tags: javascript, serverless

I've a `serverless function` that accept `N` `http` events;

```
delivery:
    handler: src/DeliveryHandler.handler
    architecture: ${self:provider.architecture}
    events:
      - http:
          path: /deliveries/cancel
          method: post
          cors: true
          private: true
      - http:
          path: /deliveries/{id}
          method: get
          cors: true
          private: true
```

The solution that I came up was to use a `switch` on the default handler;

```
const handler = async (event) => {
    switch (event.resource) {
        case '/deliveries/cancel':
            return doSomething(event)
        case '/deliveries/{id}':
            return doSomethingElse(event)
        default:
            return Promise.reject(new Error('Not found'))
    }
}
```

Is it possible and if so, how can I define a different handler for each event so I can avoid the `switch` in a single handler?